# How to display a PostGIS table on Google maps?

Tags: postgis, google-maps

I am attempting to take a shape file and display it on a map:

I can do something like this:

```
SELECT ST_AsText((ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom) as the_geom FROM shapes;
```

But the problem is I still have to do a lot of parsing of the data to get it to display on a google map. Is there a way to do this easily via google's javascript api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GeoJSON seems to be a good way to deliver what your asking.

[image]

"This simple demo shows mountain backdrop preservation areas. We're using the `showAll` parameter since there are only a handful of features and there's no sense re-fetching features with each map pan or zoom."

http://geojason.info/google-vector-layers/demos/postgis-restful-web-service-framework/

Comment: I agree - the `ST_AsGeoJSON`function is what you can use for this.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a simple option, 
http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsKML.html