# how do I create a RESTful PostGIS web Service Framework?

Tags: postgis, google-maps, postgis-2.0

I have PostGIS tables that store vectors that want to show on Google Maps. 
Read the post [How to display a PostGIS table on Google maps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22354/how-to-display-a-postgis-table-on-google-maps) But one thing that was not clear to me how do I create a RESTful PostGIS web Service Framework for feed data? I have all my data published in GeoServer, I do with it?

Comment: I think that depends on how much effort you want to invest. Having geospatial data in a database is only the first step for developing a web-map. I described how to do a gis enabled REST framework with django http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86487/overlay-my-shapefiles-stored-in-database-to-the-web-browser/88631#88631 and there is another discussion with more answers around how to start web-mapping: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/

Comment: This is a question that is WAY too broad to work in a QA-form. The short answer is: "write a web server in your programming language of choice, make it query your DB according to your needs and return the data in a format that the client can read"